# Hyperledger Fabric V1.0

Tags: java, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm working with HyperLedger V1.0 after i followed [the instructions at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html successfully](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

i decided to develop contracts using Java SDK and test them in this network, but i faced lot of problems:

-there is no shim-client in maven.

-i tried to build  /fabric/examples/.../SimpleExample using gradle build it results  errors.

is that any other way to build contract with java on HyperLEdger 'V1' please?,

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the java-sdk is not for writing chaincode, it's for user chaincode functions like deploy, invoke, query with fabric and certificate management like enroll, revoke, reenroll with fabric-ca.

Your problem is that you want to write chaincode by Java. So you may try the sample chaincode from [javasdk/test/fixture/sdkintegration/javacc](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/javacc/sample1/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/example/SimpleChaincode.java). This sample chaincode provides both `pom.xml` and `build.gradle`. So you could see the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hyperledger</groupId>
  <artifactId>shim-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

unfortunately, the shim-client is not in maven repo now... So, you can build it at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java` (the fabric source code) by `gradle build` and and `shim-client-1.0.jar` will be available in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java/build‌​/lib` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think that shim client 1.0 don't exist in maven repo.and where i i can find javasdk/test/fixture/sdkintegration/javacc folder  please

Comment: "https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java" (the javasdk source code), you may find the test folder here. And the shim-client is not in maven repo now... so, you can build it at "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java" (the fabric source code) by "gradle build" and and "shim-client-1.0.jar" will be available in github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/java/build/lib folder.

Comment: Hello zhaochy, just to clarify the terminology: if I want to develop client applications in Java that will authenticate and finalize transactions with other Java applications via Hyperledger Fabric, can you confirm these are "chaincode" applications? I guess the confusion comes from the term "build chain". TIA !

Comment: of course not chaincode. chaincode is not client side. it is deployed to fabric, and can be invoke and query from client side. For authenticate, fabric use fabric-ca (and you may config 3rd ca), users can be register, enroll, revoke, reenroll by fabric-ca, the fabric-peer has the public-key of the ca, so it can verify the certificate of each request(invoke or qurey).

Comment: zhaochy, will it be possible to migrate a traditional secure Java web service to fabric? I undertand the authentication will no longer use a root ca, but will the fabric architecture support it?

Comment: Hello, I've managed to follow the fabric-sdk-java instructions to the letter, have built my Linux Ubuntu virtual image, and successfully built docker for fabric and fabric-ca. Now, what quick Hyperledger Fabric Java test or demo can I run? Is there a procedure I can refer to? Will post my notes to Wordpress.com and add a link here.

Comment: you can try the E2E test at fabric-sdk-java, and another demo is from the fabric source, `fabric/examples/chaincode/java/chaincode_example02/`. It seems you are building fabric from the source, so, i'm not sure if it works. I'm using fabric-alpha version, and this version is ok at this moment.

Comment: Here are my complete setup notes on Windows: https://wordpress.com/post/bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com
That's where I am at.